# Slow focusing on Nexus 6 with camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop

I've bumped into the issue with slow focusing on Nexus 6.
I develop camera application and now I'm using camera2 API.

For application needs we create preview request with 2 surfaces
- SurfaceView (viewfinder)
- YUV ImageReader surface (to use data in hstogram calculation)

And there is a critical point! If just add only viewfinder surface, focusing occurs as normal. But with 2 those surfaces focusing occurs very slow with visual steps of lens moving!

Code is quite standard, written according google documentations:

```
mImageReaderPreviewYUV = ImageReader.newInstance(previewWidth, previewHeight, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);


previewRequestBuilder = camDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(getCameraSurface()); //Add surface of SurfaceView
previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReaderPreviewYUV); //Add ImageReader

mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(), captureCallback null);
```

Comment: How do you calculate the histogram? You may be slowing the camera down if the callback takes long time. I see that you specify 2 buffers for `mImageReaderPreviewYUV` - maybe the focus is stuck while you hold these two images?

Comment: Histogram isn't affects camera - already disabled for testing purposes. And all other operations is commented to leave capture callback absolutely empty. And count of buffers reduced to 1 too.

Comment: When the buffer count is 1, you are essentially saying to Android Camera not to bring new frames while in capture callback. You can log the callbacks and try to see if there is correlation between them and autofocus slow steps.

Answer (score 3):

Does the system logcat show any warnings about buffers not being available?
Is the preview frame rate slow, or is smooth (~30fps) but focusing just works oddly?

If the former, you may not be returning Image objects to the ImageReader (by closing them once done with them) at 30 fps, so the camera device is starved for buffers to fill, and cannot maintain 30fps preview.

To test this, implement the minimal ImageReaderListener.onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) method that just returns the image immediately:

```
public class TestImageListener extends ImageReaderListener {
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Image img = reader.acquireNextImage();
        img.close();
    }
  }
  ...
  mImageReaderPreviewYUV.setOnImageAvailableListener(new TestImageListener());
```

If this lets you get fluid preview, then your image processing is too slow.
As a solution, you should increase the number of buffers in your ImageReader, and the nuse the reader.acquireLatestImage() to drop older buffers and only process the newest Image each time you calculate your histogram.

Comment: Thanks for response! No, preview is fluid, it just slow focusing. I tried to simplify all callbacks and camera's management logic - no luck (

Comment: To check on a few more things, which focus mode are you using? (the default being CONTINUOUS_PICTURE) Do you trigger AF, or just letting it passively focus?

Comment: I use CONTINUOUS_PICTURE, but with AF problems the same.

Comment: What resolution and formats are your outputs? We haven't seen this on the N6 before, and would like to see if this is a bug.

Comment: SurfaceView: surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(1920, 1080);
ImageReader: mImageReaderPreview = ImageReader.newInstance(1920, 1080, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);

Also made a bug report to google's issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=95757&thanks=95757&ts=1421036143

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues on the N6 and I think it works smoother now - add the ImageReader surface before the camera surface:

```
previewRequestBuilder = camDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReaderPreviewYUV); //Add ImageReader
previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(getCameraSurface()); //Add surface of SurfaceView
```

I also tested my camera app with a N4/5.0.1 and both ways work perfectly there.